# ASP .Net Core 2.2 publish to Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-2.0

I am new to working with Azure, but recently I have published my ASP.Net core 2 app to App Service and cannot access Email templates (.html) from within the API.

API works fine, it connects to the client side and to the database, but when I try and send out an e-mail - I get exception:

> Could not find a part of the path 'D:\home\site\{ProjectName}\EmailTemplate\template.html'.

From within the code I call template using the following path format:

> ../{ProjectName}/EmailTemplate/template.html

How do I access these templates on a hosted environment?

Many thanks,
Alex

Comment: are the files published together with the app to azure? Maybe they are not included?

Comment: @jpgrassi I publish it using Visual Studio tool, but it's hard to say, as it is just a bunch of .dll files on Azure (looking in Kudo)..

Comment: yeah, but the HTMLs should be there, since they are just static files. Are they part of the solution (in VS, I mean)

Comment: no, I can't see it. Is it the way I'm storing it that is wrong? Currently, it is a part of class library project. Is there any "special" way to include it into publishing?

Comment: Also, I do get an option to "Exclude from project" when I right-click it. So it is definitely included!

Comment: When you do `dotnet publish` do you see the htmls somewhere? They have to be configured to be copied to the output directory, otherwise, they will not be included.

Comment: Right-click on the html template in vs and click `Properties`, then change `Copy to Output Directory` > `Copy Always`.

Comment: If you control the class library project, go there and mark the HTML files to be copied to the output. You can also apply a globbing pattern in the `csproj` file in the class library, so all .HTML files are copied.

Comment: that's it! worked like a charm! add it as an answer and I will accept it :) thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments.

Right-click on the html template in vs and click `Properties`, then change `Copy to Output Directory` > `Copy Always`.

Also, as @jpgrassi noted, you can also add patterns in your csproj file to include a whole directory or even all files that end with `.html`. Just right-click on your project and select `Edit <Project Name>`. Then just add this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="EmailTemplate\*.html" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: You might need to change that to `None` since it's just an HTML file and also add `CopyToOutputDirectory` / `CopyToPublishDirectory` to ensure it's always copied. The code you post will not output the files when publishing.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how I missed that. The code has been updated.